# Error installing DXA Search Module

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9.1, search

I have been following instructions to install the DXA Search Module as outlined here: https://docs.rws.com/784837/295117/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/installing-the-search-module-on-the-------------sdl-tridion-sites-content-manager

However, facing below exception on running the script. Can you please guide me on resolving the issue with the assembly as seen in error message below.
[image]

Tridion Sites 9.1/DXA 2.2

Comment: Sounds like a good old 32 x 64 bit issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p

Comment: Nuno, One question: From which location is the system trying to locate and load the dll   file ??